# Program for computations with Weyl Groups.

Tags: finite-groups, lie-algebras, computational-mathematics, sagemath, weyl-group

Let $W$ a Weyl group and $W_I$ the parabolic subgroup associated to the subset $I$ of simple roots.

Currently I am facing with the problem of computing explicitly the set of minimal coset representatives of $W/W_I$ in an efficient way.

With "in an efficient way" I mean "avoiding to compute the mcr of every element of W".

The reason is essentially computational: let consider $A_3=W_{{1,2,3,4}} <A_4$. C
Compute the mcr of each element in $A_4$ need $5!$ iterations.
A direct computation looking at the quotient will need only 5 iterations...

I am familiar with SageMath but it seems that does not exist a package for dealing with quotients by parabolic subgroups and compute their set of mcr.

Moreover I know that there exists some ad hoc functions in Lie, but I am not very familiar with this program.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make this computation using sage?
Are there some other even intuitive programs that can I use (and that support polynomial computations too)?

Comment: For Weyl groups there are well known combinatorial descriptions of the minimal length coset representatives. Why would you want to compute them from scratch?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I have to make some computations with mcr (MANY computation) and find every time the right combinatorial description will not to be efficient...

Comment: @Matt Samuel I know combinatorial descriptions only in Classical Types, do you have a reference for the Exceptional ones?

Comment: I've gathered it from papers mostly and I don't know of a central reference. I got [this](http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=BUMI_2000_8_3B_3_699_0) as the first result of a Google search, perhaps a deeper search would be fruitful. The point is that there are not a whole lot of families of finite crystallographic Coxeter groups, and the groups are quite large, so a direct computation can't possibly be efficient and it's much better to go with a simplified description on a case by case basis, despite how ugly it might seem.

Comment: Nice reference! I will try...

Comment: CoCoA http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/